# Error when trying to get the values from a variable into a text file

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have prepared a script to find and disabled Active Directory users who are inactive for 40 days. I want the script output file to include the DisplayName of the accounts that got disabled by each run.

Example:

> Daniel Andrews,
> Peter Huyen,
> Ashoka Handagama

When I run the script I get the following error:

> Transcript started, output file is C:\temp\Test\Disable_and_Move_User_Accounts_20230522_11-15-37.log
> PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> TerminatingError(Set-ADUser): "The requested operation did not satisfy one or more constraints associated with the class of the object"
> Error occured updating account desmond_palima. The requested operation did not satisfy one or more constraints associated with the class of the object

The script I developed is as follows. Can you please help me to fix it?

---

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 

$inactiveDays = 40
$disableDaysInactive=(Get-Date).AddDays(-($inactiveDays))
$todaysDate = (Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd_HH-mm-ss")


$LogFile = "C:\temp\Test\Disable_and_Move_User_Accounts_$todaysDate.log"
$DisabledOU = 'OU=Test Disable,OU=User Accounts,OU=Car,DC=car,DC=com'
$path= "OU=Test,OU=User Accounts,OU=Car,DC=car,DC=com"
 

$userlist = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $path -Filter {(Enabled -eq $True)} -Properties * | Where-Object {($_.description -Notlike "*Service Account*") -and ($_.lastLogonDate -lt $disableDaysInactive) -and ($_.lastLogonDate -ne $NULL)} 

Start-Transcript -path $LogFile

if ($userlist) {    

ForEach ($user in $userlist){        
$desc = "Disabled on $(Get-Date) for being inactive for 40 days $($user.Description)"         

try {            
Set-ADUser -Identity $user -Description $desc -Enabled $false            
Move-ADObject -Identity $user -TargetPath $DisabledOU 
Write-Output $user.DisplayName
}        
catch {            
'Error occured updating account {0}. {1}' -f $user.SamAccountName, $_        }     }}
else {    "No users met the search criteria."

}
```

Comment: A good strategy to troubleshoot problems is to create a [mre]. Your error message also helps to narrow down the problem. It might be related to `Set-ADUser`. So throw away everything else and concentrate on that cmdlet. For example, you could check what happens if you get an AD user and then set it like you do in your code wall above. Does it work? If so, does it also work for "desmond_palima"?

Comment: It's faster just to use breakpoints and find out where it fails and when it fails - then you can work on why it fails and remediate the issue.